# Find MIN value in a LIMITed set

Tags: mysql, sql, min, sql-limit

I need to find a minimum value from limited number of rows in single column. Let's say I have this `results` table:

```
-----------------------------------------
|  id  |  category  |  class  |  score  |
-----------------------------------------
|   1  |  contest1  |  seven  |    55   |
|   2  |  contest1  |  sixth  |    78   |
|   3  |  contest2  |  seven  |    20   |
|   4  |  contest1  |  eleven |    21   |
|   5  |  contest2  |  eleven |    56   |
|   6  |  contest3  |  ten    |    66   |
|   7  |  contest3  |  ten    |    90   |
|   8  |  contest3  |  nine   |    91   |
|   9  |  contest2  |  seven  |    30   |
|  10  |  contest1  |  nine   |    51   |
-----------------------------------------
```

Now I need to create a set of values which are >= 50 AND limited to 3 rows. Like this:

```
-----------------------------------------
|  id  |  category  |  class  |  score  |
-----------------------------------------
|   1  |  contest1  |  seven  |    55   |
|   2  |  contest1  |  sixth  |    78   |
|  10  |  contest1  |  nine   |    51   |
-----------------------------------------
```

In this set I have to find MIN value, which is quite simple actually, but only if I do it manually for each category. This query works perfectly:

```
SELECT MIN(t1.score) 
FROM (
SELECT category, score 
FROM results 
WHERE category = "contest1" AND score >= 50 
ORDER BY score DESC 
LIMIT 3
) t1
```

And gives the right result:

```
-------------------
|  MIN(t1.score)  |
-------------------
|        51       |
-------------------
```

However, I can't write a query which will do it automatically for each category. In a real table there are over a hundred categories with thousands of score values. How can I find minimum value for each category within a limited set of rows?

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()` to get the "first" three rows for each category:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by category order by sid) as seqnum
      from results r
      where score >= 50
     ) r
where seqnum <= 3;
```

This returns the first three rows based on the `id` for each category.  You can then get the minimum:

```
select category, min(score)
from (select r.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by category order by sid) as seqnum
      from results r
      where score >= 50
     ) r
where seqnum <= 3
group by category;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm afraid that's not an option for me cause I have MySQL 5.7.

Comment: @sauromates . . . Why would you want the minimum of three *arbitrary* rows anyway?  Why not just use the overall minimum?

Comment: because overall minimum would be 50 in every category, and I need minimum of 25% top scores in range from 50 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't enough rows to make an impact.

But it uses also rwo number to get 3 smallest scores bigger than 50 for every category

> ```
> CREATE TABLE results  (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `category` VARCHAR(8),
>   `class` VARCHAR(6),
>   `score` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO results 
>   (`id`, `category`, `class`, `score`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'contest1', 'seven', '55'),
>   ('2', 'contest1', 'sixth', '78'),
>   ('3', 'contest2', 'seven', '20'),
>   ('4', 'contest1', 'eleven', '21'),
>   ('5', 'contest2', 'eleven', '56'),
>   ('6', 'contest3', 'ten', '66'),
>   ('7', 'contest3', 'ten', '90'),
>   ('8', 'contest3', 'nine', '91'),
>   ('9', 'contest2', 'seven', '30'),
>   ('10', 'contest1', 'nine', '51');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
> `id`, `category`, `class`, `score` 
> FROM(SELECT 
> IF(`category` = @cat,@rown := @rown + 1 ,@rown := 1) rownum
> ,`id`
> , @cat := `category` 'category'
> , `class`
> , `score` 
> FROM (SELECT * FROM results ORDER By `category`, `score` )r1,(SELECT @rown := 0, @cat := '') t1
> WHERE `score` > 50 ) t1
> WHERE rownum < 4
> ```

> ```
> id | category | class  | score
> -: | :------- | :----- | ----:
> 10 | contest1 | nine   |    51
>  1 | contest1 | seven  |    55
>  2 | contest1 | sixth  |    78
>  5 | contest2 | eleven |    56
>  6 | contest3 | ten    |    66
>  7 | contest3 | ten    |    90
>  8 | contest3 | nine   |    91
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=022773617081e1a35cdaf9ff7165785f)*